# "No package X available" when trying to install any package on CentOS 6.8

Tags: centos, php

I want to install PHP 7 on my CentOS VPS. There are many tutorials on the web about this, but in every attempt for every package, I get this error:

> No package php70w available.

(For each package name attempted.)

This seems to me to be a basic fault, maybe my fault. I am not yet familiar with CentOS.

`yum list php` produces this output:

```
[root@server ~]# yum list php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.trisect.eu
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi-php56: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-php70: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-safe: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * updates: centos.trisect.eu
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

`yum search php` provides this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.trisect.eu
 * epel: epel.mirrors.ovh.net
 * extras: mirrors.ircam.fr
 * remi-php56: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-php70: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * remi-safe: fr.mirror.babylon.network
 * updates: centos.trisect.eu
 * webtatic: uk.repo.webtatic.com
=============================== N/S Matched: php ===============================
cups-php.x86_64 : Common Unix Printing System - php module
graphviz-php.x86_64 : PHP extension for graphviz
nntpgrab-php.x86_64 : PHP module which allows PHP scripts to communicate with
                    : NNTPGrab
perl-PHP-Serialization.noarch : Converts between PHP's serialize() output and
                              : the equivalent Perl structure
remctl-php.x86_64 : PHP interface to remctl
rh-php56.x86_64 : Package that installs PHP 5.6
rh-php56-php.x86_64 : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
rh-php56-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath
                           : library
rh-php56-php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
rh-php56-php-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
rh-php56-php-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP
                        : applications
rh-php56-php-dbg.x86_64 : The interactive PHP debugger
rh-php56-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
rh-php56-php-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
rh-php56-php-enchant.x86_64 : Enchant spelling extension for PHP applications
rh-php56-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
rh-php56-php-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics
                       : library
rh-php56-php-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP
                        : library
rh-php56-php-imap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
rh-php56-php-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
rh-php56-php-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
rh-php56-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need
                             : multi-byte string handling
rh-php56-php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL
                            : databases
rh-php56-php-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
rh-php56-php-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP
                        : applications
rh-php56-php-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
rh-php56-php-pecl-mongo.x86_64 : PHP MongoDB database driver
rh-php56-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 : PECL package for debugging PHP scripts
rh-php56-php-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
rh-php56-php-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process
                            : interfaces
rh-php56-php-pspell.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using pspell
                           : interfaces
rh-php56-php-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode
                           : library
rh-php56-php-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed
                         : devices
rh-php56-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP
                         : protocol
rh-php56-php-tidy.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides tidy library support
rh-php56-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
rh-php56-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC
                           : protocol
rh-php56-runtime.x86_64 : Package that handles rh-php56 Software Collection.
rh-php56-scldevel.x86_64 : Package shipping development files for rh-php56
rh-php70.x86_64 : Package that installs PHP 7.0
rh-php70-php.x86_64 : PHP scripting language for creating dynamic web sites
rh-php70-php-bcmath.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the bcmath
                           : library
rh-php70-php-cli.x86_64 : Command-line interface for PHP
rh-php70-php-common.x86_64 : Common files for PHP
rh-php70-php-dba.x86_64 : A database abstraction layer module for PHP
                        : applications
rh-php70-php-dbg.x86_64 : The interactive PHP debugger
rh-php70-php-devel.x86_64 : Files needed for building PHP extensions
rh-php70-php-embedded.x86_64 : PHP library for embedding in applications
rh-php70-php-enchant.x86_64 : Enchant spelling extension for PHP applications
rh-php70-php-fpm.x86_64 : PHP FastCGI Process Manager
rh-php70-php-gd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the gd graphics
                       : library
rh-php70-php-gmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the GNU MP
                        : library
rh-php70-php-imap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use IMAP
rh-php70-php-intl.x86_64 : Internationalization extension for PHP applications
rh-php70-php-json.x86_64 : JavaScript Object Notation extension for PHP
rh-php70-php-ldap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use LDAP
rh-php70-php-mbstring.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which need
                             : multi-byte string handling
rh-php70-php-mysqlnd.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL
                            : databases
rh-php70-php-odbc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use ODBC databases
rh-php70-php-pdo.x86_64 : A database access abstraction module for PHP
                        : applications
rh-php70-php-pear.noarch : PHP Extension and Application Repository framework
rh-php70-php-pgsql.x86_64 : A PostgreSQL database module for PHP
rh-php70-php-process.x86_64 : Modules for PHP script using system process
                            : interfaces
rh-php70-php-pspell.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using pspell
                           : interfaces
rh-php70-php-recode.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications for using the recode
                           : library
rh-php70-php-snmp.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that query SNMP-managed
                         : devices
rh-php70-php-soap.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that use the SOAP
                         : protocol
rh-php70-php-tidy.x86_64 : Standard PHP module provides tidy library support
rh-php70-php-xml.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use XML
rh-php70-php-xmlrpc.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications which use the XML-RPC
                           : protocol
rh-php70-php-zip.x86_64 : ZIP archive management extension for PHP
rh-php70-runtime.x86_64 : Package that handles rh-php70 Software Collection.
rh-php70-scldevel.x86_64 : Package shipping development files for rh-php70
rrdtool-php.x86_64 : PHP RRDtool bindings
sclo-php54-php-pecl-propro-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php54-php-pecl-propro developer
                                        : files (header)
sclo-php54-php-pecl-raphf-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php54-php-pecl-raphf developer
                                       : files (header)
sclo-php54-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 : PECL package for debugging PHP scripts
sclo-php55-php-pecl-propro-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php55-php-pecl-propro developer
                                        : files (header)
sclo-php55-php-pecl-raphf-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php55-php-pecl-raphf developer
                                       : files (header)
sclo-php55-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 : PECL package for debugging PHP scripts
sclo-php56-php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 : Replacement for the standard PHP
                                    : serializer
sclo-php56-php-pecl-mongodb.x86_64 : MongoDB driver for PHP
sclo-php56-php-pecl-propro-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php56-php-pecl-propro developer
                                        : files (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-raphf-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php56-php-pecl-raphf developer
                                       : files (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-selinux.x86_64 : SELinux binding for PHP scripting language
sclo-php56-php-pecl-uuid.x86_64 : Universally Unique Identifier extension for
                                : PHP
sclo-php70-php-pecl-igbinary.x86_64 : Replacement for the standard PHP
                                    : serializer
sclo-php70-php-pecl-mongodb.x86_64 : MongoDB driver for PHP
sclo-php70-php-pecl-propro-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php70-php-pecl-propro developer
                                        : files (header)
sclo-php70-php-pecl-raphf-devel.x86_64 : sclo-php70-php-pecl-raphf developer
                                       : files (header)
sclo-php70-php-pecl-selinux.x86_64 : SELinux binding for PHP scripting language
sclo-php70-php-pecl-uuid.x86_64 : Universally Unique Identifier extension for
                                : PHP
sclo-php70-php-pecl-xdebug.x86_64 : PECL package for debugging PHP scripts
sphinx-php.x86_64 : PHP API for Sphinx
uuid-php.x86_64 : PHP support for Universally Unique Identifier library
uwsgi-plugin-php.x86_64 : uWSGI - Plugin for PHP support
apm-web.noarch : Alternative PHP Monitor web application
drupal6-views_customfield.noarch : Provides a number of custom views fields
                                 : (rownumber, phpcode, ...)
lighttpd-fastcgi.x86_64 : FastCGI module and spawning helper for lighttpd and
                        : PHP configuration
limph.noarch : A PHP5-compatible network host/service poller with web interface
rh-php56-build.x86_64 : Package shipping basic build configuration
rh-php56-php-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache
rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 : Support for JSON serialization
rh-php56-php-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 : JSON developer files (header)
rh-php56-php-pecl-memcache.x86_64 : Extension to work with the Memcached caching
                                  : daemon
rh-php70-build.x86_64 : Package shipping basic build configuration
rh-php70-php-opcache.x86_64 : The Zend OPcache
sclo-php54-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 : APC User Cache
sclo-php54-php-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64 : APCu developer files (header)
sclo-php54-php-pecl-apfd.x86_64 : Always Populate Form Data
sclo-php54-php-pecl-http.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support
sclo-php54-php-pecl-http-devel.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support developer files
                                      : (header)
sclo-php54-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64 : Extension to create and modify images using
                                   : ImageMagick
sclo-php54-php-pecl-imagick-devel.x86_64 : imagick extension developer files
                                         : (header)
sclo-php54-php-pecl-propro.x86_64 : Property proxy
sclo-php54-php-pecl-raphf.x86_64 : Resource and persistent handles factory
sclo-php54-php-pecl-uploadprogress.x86_64 : An extension to track progress of a
                                          : file upload
sclo-php55-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 : APC User Cache
sclo-php55-php-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64 : APCu developer files (header)
sclo-php55-php-pecl-apfd.x86_64 : Always Populate Form Data
sclo-php55-php-pecl-http.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support
sclo-php55-php-pecl-http-devel.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support developer files
                                      : (header)
sclo-php55-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64 : Extension to create and modify images using
                                   : ImageMagick
sclo-php55-php-pecl-imagick-devel.x86_64 : imagick extension developer files
                                         : (header)
sclo-php55-php-pecl-propro.x86_64 : Property proxy
sclo-php55-php-pecl-raphf.x86_64 : Resource and persistent handles factory
sclo-php55-php-pecl-uploadprogress.x86_64 : An extension to track progress of a
                                          : file upload
sclo-php56-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 : APC User Cache
sclo-php56-php-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64 : APCu developer files (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-apfd.x86_64 : Always Populate Form Data
sclo-php56-php-pecl-http.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support
sclo-php56-php-pecl-http-devel.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support developer files
                                      : (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-igbinary-devel.x86_64 : Igbinary developer files (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-imagick.x86_64 : Extension to create and modify images using
                                   : ImageMagick
sclo-php56-php-pecl-imagick-devel.x86_64 : imagick extension developer files
                                         : (header)
sclo-php56-php-pecl-lzf.x86_64 : Extension to handle LZF de/compression
sclo-php56-php-pecl-propro.x86_64 : Property proxy
sclo-php56-php-pecl-raphf.x86_64 : Resource and persistent handles factory
sclo-php56-php-pecl-solr2.x86_64 : Object oriented API to Apache Solr
sclo-php56-php-pecl-uploadprogress.x86_64 : An extension to track progress of a
                                          : file upload
sclo-php56-php-pecl-xattr.x86_64 : Extended attributes
sclo-php70-php-pecl-apcu.x86_64 : APC User Cache
sclo-php70-php-pecl-apcu-bc.x86_64 : APCu Backwards Compatibility Module
sclo-php70-php-pecl-apcu-devel.x86_64 : APCu developer files (header)
sclo-php70-php-pecl-apfd.x86_64 : Always Populate Form Data
sclo-php70-php-pecl-http.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support
sclo-php70-php-pecl-http-devel.x86_64 : Extended HTTP support developer files
                                      : (header)
sclo-php70-php-pecl-igbinary-devel.x86_64 : Igbinary developer files (header)
sclo-php70-php-pecl-lzf.x86_64 : Extension to handle LZF de/compression
sclo-php70-php-pecl-propro.x86_64 : Property proxy
sclo-php70-php-pecl-raphf.x86_64 : Resource and persistent handles factory
sclo-php70-php-pecl-solr2.x86_64 : Object oriented API to Apache Solr
sclo-php70-php-pecl-uploadprogress.x86_64 : An extension to track progress of a
                                          : file upload
sclo-php70-php-pecl-xattr.x86_64 : Extended attributes
squirrelmail.noarch : webmail client written in php
tiquit.noarch : A PHP5-compatible help desk incident tracking/knowledgebase
              : system
xhprof.noarch : A Hierarchical Profiler for PHP - Web interface
zephir.noarch : Zephir language for creation of extensions for PHP.

  Name and summary matches only, use "search all" for everything.
```

Comment: Have you tried `yum list php` or `yum search php`?

Comment: @david25272 question edited...

Comment: Check for exclude directive in yum configuration file.

Comment: this is my exclude directive : `exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*` and I dont know anything about that... :(

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a cpanel/directadmin/someotherpanel box, not a centos one.

```
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*
```

This means that with your configuration, yum will never pull these packages from any repository, as they are managed differently.

Comment: I have not cpanel... I have directadmin installed by VPS administrator and now he is gone and I...

Comment: directadmin is same problem, they heavily alter the distro by using their own version of httpd, php, mysql...  so you have to ask directadmin support how to upgrade php, or cleanup evrything installed by directadmin and switch to standard packages.